# iOS simulator not found in KMM project

Tags: android, ios, xcode, android-studio, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm trying to build a KMM project using Android Studio. I can see two separate configurations as well, each for AndroidApp and iOSApp. But the iOSApp configuration doesn't have an Execution target. Neither does it show any simulators in the dropdown.
I do have Xcode installed and have run other iOS apps successfully in the iPhone Simulator.

p.s. I'm on M1 mac

[image]

Comment: Select device from 'Execution target' dropdown (#4) first

Answer (score 0):

once you run the project you'll see a iosApp.xcodeproj file being generated .. make sure your android studio pane is in project mode.

Once a successful build is done you'll be able to open this .xcodeproj file from within xcode

I have not been able to do that as well. If there is a build failure the reason is it is not finding the common folder. To do that open the terminal and run gradlew tasks.There
should be a task allowing you to ready the shared folder with xcode

Comment: I tried that but that gives me build failure. However, I'm more concerned about not being able to run iOS Simulator from the Android Studio iOSApp configuration itself.

Answer (score 0):

First select the device in which device you want to use in simulator then find build option and then click on it, your simulator automatically will popup on the screen

Answer (score 0):

I resolve it by restarting Android Studio. After restart AS, devices appear in the drop list of "execution target"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a plugin-related problem, which I successfully resolved by performing the following steps:

1. Installed the most recent version of the Android Studio, specifically Iguana | 2023.2.1 Canary 3.
2. Manually added the KMM plugin version 0.8.0(232)-7, which can be found at this URL: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/14936-kotlin-multiplatform-mobile/versions/dev

I hope this helps!